# wrapper function in throwing error " as ‘p’ was not declared in this scop"

Tags: c++, c, string, wrapper, member-functions

I am trying to access `C++` function (f1) and string a from `c` file using a wrapper function. Code below.

Error thrown is

> Error : error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
>   double d = f11( p,i);

**1.h**

```
double f11(struct c* p, int i);
```

**1.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
class c
{
    public:   double f1(int i)  // how can i access from c 
    {
        cout<<"I am in c++";
    }
    public : string a;   // how can i access string from c
};

extern "C"  double f11(c* p, int i) // wrapper function
{
    return p->f1(i);
}
```

**2.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "1.h"
int main()
{
    int i=9;
    double d = f11( p,i);
}
```

Comment: where you declared p ?

Comment: @venki p is object of class c in 1.cpp file and in 1.h

Comment: Yes, but 2.c has no way to create an object of class c.

Comment: @user3386109 no actually 2.c is not creating a object if u see i have created object in 1.h and included in 2.c by the way  if i comment this function call double d = f11( p,i); from the 2.c it  is good

Comment: 1.h declares a function that takes two arguments, a pointer and an int. 1.h does not create an object.

Comment: @user4950013 what is scope of p in 1.h file ?

Answer (score 2):

If you manually include the contents of "1.h" in main.cpp, it would look:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f11(struct c* p, int i);

int main()
{
    int i=9;
    double d = f11( p,i);
}
```

There are several problems there.

1. You haven't declared `p` before using it in the call to `f11`.
2. You don't have any way of constructing an object of type `struct c` in `main`. Even if you were to fix the compiler errors by providing declarations of `struct c` and `p`, you'll run into run time problems since the only way to initialize `p` will be to initialize it to NULL. That wouldn't do you any good since you have a line

   ```
   return p->f1(i);
   ```

   in `f11`.
3. Your declaration and definition of `f11` will result in linker error. If you want to implement the function as `extern "C"`, you'll also have to declare it as `extern "C"`.

   ```
   extern "C" double f11(c* p, int i);
   ```
4. In 1.cpp, the member function `f1` does not return a double. That is cause for undefined error, if the compiler does not report that as an error.

See working code at http://ideone.com/aVFWFJ. Please note that I changed the implementation of `c::f1` so it does not crash.